# GitLab Runner for GitLab server with CA signed certificate failing with: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ssl-certificate, gitlab

My company changed the Certification Authority (it was a single CA and now we have a root CA and an intermediate CA). I changed the configuration in the GitLab instance with success and moved to the runner (that is on a Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS). I tried to follow the [GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html) without success.

I followed the default approach [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html#supported-options-for-self-signed-certificates-targeting-the-gitlab-server) that says  "Default - Read the system certificate", and so I added the certificates (CA and Intermediate) to the Ubuntu CA list. Everything seemed to work because the runner appears in GitLab.

I start a job and I get:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.5.0 (3afdaba6)
  on RUN01 12ccbb74
Using Docker executor with image node:latest ...
Pulling docker image node:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:ab773999a02271b25a9f3bce46018fc3ad46a7f922a5e3e8712b6d1c7087c415 for node:latest ...
Running on runner-12ccbb74-project-73-concurrent-0 via (...)...
00:02
Fetching changes...
00:01
HEAD is now at 60b6860 Update dependency mocha to v9
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@(...).git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get issuer certificate
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I then added (on the GitLab instance) the complete chain to the certificate file, and the error changed to `SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain`.

My logic*: It works for Ubuntu, but it doesn't for Docker. So I moved to the [Trusting TLS certificates for Docker and Kubernetes executors](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html#trusting-tls-certificates-for-docker-and-kubernetes-executors) section.

What I've tried so far, without success:

1. I added the Root CA certificate to `/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/ca.crt`.
2. I also tried with a file with the Root CA and Intermediate CA in a chain.
3. I added `volumes = ["/cache", "/path/to-ca-cert-dir/ca.crt:/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/ca.crt:ro"]` to the `config.toml` file. But I'm almost sure I should replace `/path/to-ca-cert-dir` with something. I just don't know what.

*Update: When I installed the GitLab Runner I followed [Install using the GitLab repository for Debian/Ubuntu/CentOS/RedHat](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html), so Docker/K8s instructions didn't make sense. I posted an [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1077247/362482) on how I was able to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make it work following the third option in [Supported options for self-signed certificates targeting the GitLab server](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html#supported-options-for-self-signed-certificates-targeting-the-gitlab-server), that says:

> Read a PEM certificate: GitLab Runner reads the PEM certificate (DER format is not supported) from a predefined file:
>
> /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/hostname.crt on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as root.
>
> If your server address is https://my.gitlab.server.com:8443/, create the certificate file at: /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/my.gitlab.server.com.crt.

So I just added the complete chain (GitLab certificate, Intermediate, Root) to a file name `/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/<gitlab-url>.crt`. Restarted the services with `gitlab-runner restart` and the job is working.

Comment: The `volume = [..., "path/to/ca.crt:/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/ca.crt:ro"]` method had been working fine for me with Docker executors on an Ubuntu host, with both Ubuntu and CentOS containers. But in trying to transition from a Docker executor to Podman, I ran into this, specifically when the GitLab helper image clones/fetches the git repo. Putting a copy of my cert in the Host's dir as you describe fixed it!